# Fetch Multiple Rows in IBM DB2

Tags: mysql, sql, db2

I want to fetch top 2 rows in DB2 for Employee table.

Table data

```
EE_No. STATE
1.     Arizona
2.     Arizona
3.     Arizona
4.     New Mexico
5.     New Mexico

Query Result
1. Arizona
2. Arizona
4. New Mexico
5. New Mexico
```

```
Select Distinct
Ee-id
State
From Emloyee
Order by ee_no
FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Its now really clear what result you are actually attempting to achieve. Can you have another go, maybe just add the resultset you want

Comment: Why did you tag mysql?

Comment: What is the issue with your current query?

Comment: The question is not clear to me. What's the expected result?

Comment: I have a single table with millions of rows. I need to query the table in such a way that output should reflect TOP 10 employees from the State(which could be Arizona, New Mexico etc..) on the basis of hire date.

Answer (score 1):

```
select ee_no, state
from (
select a.*, row_number()over(partition by state order by ee_no)as rn
from yourtable a ) 
where rn<=2;
```